# File not found on Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So I'm trying to include an h file. Here's what that looks like [image]

Then I get

```
SIOSocket.h file not found
```

But here are the files....

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The right way is the following:

```
#import "SIOSocket.h"
```

Comment: @user302975 sorrry I did not mean include its import  `#import "SIOSocket.h"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
#import <SIOSocket.h>
```

you want:

```
#import "SIOSocket.h"
```

The difference is the `"..."` and the `<...>`

Comment: The issue is no longer the import

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid to import libs manually. The life is to short to lose time on that.

Try **[cocoapods](http://www.cocoapods.org)** instead.

The library you are using supports it. You need only to follow the guide provided on the [website](http://www.cocoapods.org).

To resume it, you need to:

-Install *cocapods* if needed

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

-Create a file in the root directory of your project that contains the following lines. (Choose the minimum version of iOS you are targeting for)

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'SIOSocket', '~> 0.0'
```

-Run pod `pod install`

Use the create workspace

now you can import the lib using

```
#import <SIOSocket/SIOSocket.h>
```

The cocoapods website has all the details you'll need